# Removing Doxygen code fragments/references

Tags: config, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen for generating documentation in my programming projects. And while I find it quite easy to configure and use I can't seem to find a way to hide the source references it adds to the HTML output.

I'm using these two directives in the configuration file:

```
SOURCE_BROWSER = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS = NO
```

But it only seems to hide the "Definition at line  of file ."

What I want removed is what's in the red rectangle below:

[image]

Is there a directive to also hide the source code it references? (Other than doing the hack'ish thing and remove it with CSS or jQuery)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "source references" please?  There are quite a few things that doxygen outputs that could be called that. Adding an example to the question would be best.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have just added an image of what I want removed.

Comment: What's your setting of `INLINE_SOURCES` in the doxyfile?

Comment: That did the trick. It was "YES". I thought I had tried changing it but clearly not. Thanks mate :-) If you add it as a reply to the thread I'll select it as the right one and close it so others may benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your setting on `INLINE_SOURCES` is set to `NO`.

Description from the manual - it looks like you have this `YES`

> Setting the INLINE_SOURCES tag to YES will include the body of functions, classes and enums directly into the documentation.